# Как правильно применять require в php

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap

Добрый день. Решаю, казалось бы, обыденную проблему:
Есть простой сайт, на нем верхнее меню. Пункты меню подключаются к странице при помощи `require('menu/up-menu.php');`. Вопрос вот какой: почему, если простой html разметкой вставить пункты меню, то все смотриться как надо, а есть подключить из стороннего файла (как показано выше), то все пункты меню съезжают немного вправа и вниз. Отмечу, что сталкивался с этим во множестве шаблонов. Замечу, если взять пункты меню из файла и вставить их прямо в код страницы - все в огне, все работает как часы, как только переносим обратно в файл и подключаем файлом - разметка чуть-чуть сдвигается. Мне интересна причина такого поведения. Замечу, что в файле меню нет ничего, кроме html разметки, которая была взята с шаблона, оба файла находятся в 1 и той же кодировке и оба они php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приветствую.

Скорее всего, это UTF-8 BOM, потеря закрывающих тегов при переносе и/или лишние пробелы в menu/up-menu.php.

Если бы Вы привели код, возможно, ответ мог бы быть точнее.

Comment: И это правильный ответ! Спасибо большое. Проблема была в UTF-8 BOM. Заменил на UTF-8 без BOM - все работает прекрасно!

Answer (score 2):

Оператор `require` не имеет к данной проблеме никакого отношения, и никакого "неправильного" варианта его применения не существует. Все что делает этот оператор - это вставляет определенный код в указанное место, и при этом **ничего от себя не добавляет.** Если вместо этого оператора поместить в скрипт содержимое подключаемого файла, то результат будет на 100% идентичным.

Любые **проблемы могут быть вызваны только содержимым подключаемого файла.** В нем и следует искать причину - будь это BOM или что-либо ещё.

Answer (score 1):

Вы делаете перевод строки при подключении require? Возможно это играет свою роль.

Answer (score 0):

А результирующая верстка то одинаковая?

Если нет, значит что-то где-то потерялось/добавилось. Попробуйте воспользоваться require_once